# C# - Search JSON Package for an ID

Tags: c#, ios, json, xamarin.forms, json.net

I'm building an app in Xamarin Forms - C# and I have a JSON package that has a collection of records that have IDs associated with them.

For example, here's the JSON response package:

```
{
   "number": "100",
   "balance": "30.000000"
},
{
   "number": "101",
   "balance": "100.000000"
},
{
   "number": "103",
   "balance": "50.000000"
},
```

Here's my code that pulls out all the values:

```
var GetGiftCardBalanceUrl = "https://example.com/wp-json/wc-pimwick/v1/pw-gift-cards";

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GetGiftCardBalanceUrl);

HttpContent content = response.Content;
var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

GiftCardsRoot mygiftcards = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GiftCardsRoot>(json);
```

And here's my model:

```
public class GiftCardsRoot
{
   public List<GiftCardsMyArray> GiftCardsMyArray { get; set; }
}

public class GiftCardsMyArray
{
   public string number { get; set; }
   public string balance { get; set; }
}
```

How would I retrieve the balance value if I were to enter the number value in C#?

For example:

If JSON response package number value contains:

> 101

Then it would return:

> "100.00000"

NOTE. The API that I'm using is very new and they don't have any endpoints to retrieve records based off IDs yet so I'm looking for a workaround for now.

Comment: Can you show the model `GiftCardsRoot` ?

Comment: So then your data is really an array? Your data doesn't match your model. Can you show a full set of data? You can leave out the array objects. I just want to see how it's wrapped.

Comment: `var bob = mygiftcards.GiftCardsMyArray.FirstOrDefault(z => z.number == "101");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using:

```
var bob = mygiftcards.GiftCardsMyArray.FirstOrDefault(z => z.number == "101")
```

This will find the first element in the array that has the `number` of 101.